# Activity view doesn't showing

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app  I use a splash screen activity for save dravables as files on sd card or in built-in memory. It's works well, but this activity doesn't show content view.Why this activity save files but doesn't show content view?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    for (int i = 0; i < DRAWABLES.length; i++) {
        saveDrawables(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), DRAWABLES[i]),
                String.valueOf(i + 2));
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MotivateActivity.class));
    finish();

}

public void saveDrawables(Bitmap drawable, String drawableName) {

    try {
        String filename = drawableName + ".jpg";
        Log.i("Local filename:", "" + filename);

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/MotivateMe/");
        File file = new File(dir, filename);

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        drawable.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutput);
        fileOutput.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: why are you starting activity again in onCreate method?

Comment: Actaully what's your problem????Your code is not clear??

Comment: "why are you starting activity again in onCreate method?" , i'm start another activity

Comment: No, that's not the way sir. Use an Asynctask and when the task is completed, then start your next activity.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the instructions here or maybe it would help :)
**http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/**

Answer (score 2):

The code is really wrong in a lot of ways…

but for the sake of simplicity, let's just say that you're doing the work (loading your images) in the wrong place.

I suggest you read two things.

1) [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

2) [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (where you should be actually doing that work).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show the file which you have saved because before the activity renders the layout you have started the another activity in your `onCreate()` method. That is why is just run the code of saving image and then immediately starts the new activity.

Answer (score -1):

Modify onCreate code as below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    final Handler handler=new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < DRAWABLES.length; i++) {
                saveDrawables(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), DRAWABLES[i]),
                        String.valueOf(i + 2));
            }
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MotivateActivity.class));
                        finish();
                }
            },1000);                
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Since you are doing the operation in UI thread, the thread will hang there and you will not see the splash screen. Once the thread completes, you are calling the finish, so you cannot see the splash screen any more. In above code, I've created a new thread which will do that task, mean while the activity will load as normal. Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Although this may "solve" the issue, the practice of starting a thread in the onCreate method just killed 100 kittens. This is bad bad bad bad. Don't do this.

Comment: And I love the hack of adding 1000 ms to the post delayed…

Comment: As per android documentation, you are supposed to create a seperate thread for doing long running operations.. Otherwise it will create issues with the UI thread and may also result in "ANR".

Comment: @MartínMarconcini if his requirement may contains to show the splash screen and if the operation finished within milli seconds, the same problem will arise..... :P

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to create another thread to run long operations, might as well do it the right way. You don't HAVE to use an async task (although for such a simple operation I'd do), but why the post delayed? Don't do all that in the onCreate method of your activity… let your activity be created and then do the work and THEN go to another activity.

Comment: @ArtemCherkasov Not able to see the splash screen again?? if thats the case, just try my new edit...which forcefully makes the screen there for 1 second

Comment: @MartínMarconcini previously i wrote the code with "post" only, then i thought like, he might be having the requirement to show the splash screen...